# Unable to retrieve output of databricks notebook to ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a scenario of passing the notebook output to loop to fetch 4 Id's to a variable but got below error. can someone help me on how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfurF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsiEt.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA5j4.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRp7j.png)

Comment: please paste the error message as text also.

Answer (score 0):

The Item section in your `ForEach activity` should be like:

`@{activity(‘Notebook1’).output.runOutput}`

[image]

When accessing that item with the `ForEach`, use `Set Variable activity to read the output from the Notebook and **create a variable with Array type** by clicking on` + New` under Variable tab.

[image]

Now use `@item().SurveyID[0]` because the variable holding data is an Array type so it can be selected. In your case, since the `SurveyID` is a string type and you cannot implement property selection on string type because it isn’t supported.

[image]

Comment: Hi Utkarsh, 

 Thank you for your answer. I have tried this approach earlier but no luck. I got an error Expression of type: 'string' does not match the field:'items' in for each activity. 

Thanks,
Venkat

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you let me know that is it possible to pass table data from notebook output directly without converting it to JSON to ADF.